# Evaluating iszero function

Tags: lambda-calculus

$\underline{iszero}$ function is defined as

$$
\underline{iszero} = \lambda n. n(\lambda x. \underline{false})\underline{true}
$$

I want to show that $\underline{iszero} \ \underline{5} = \underline{false}$.

Here's my try:

$$
\underline{iszero} \ \underline{5} = (\lambda n. n(\lambda x. \underline{false})\underline{true})\underline{5}
= \underline{5}(\lambda x. \underline{false})\underline{true}
= (\lambda fx. f^5 x)(\lambda x. \underline{false})\underline{true}
= (\lambda x. (\lambda x_0. \underline{false})^5 x)\underline{true}
= (\lambda x_0. \underline{false})^5 \underline{true}
$$

Use induction:

$$
(\lambda x_0. \underline{false})\underline{true} = \underline{false}
$$

$$
(\lambda x_0. \underline{false})^2 \underline{true}
= (\lambda x_0. \underline{false})((\lambda x_0. \underline{false})\underline{true})
= (\lambda x_0. \underline{false})\underline{false}
= \underline{false}
$$

$$
\vdots
$$

$$
(\lambda x_0. \underline{false})^3 \underline{true} = \underline{false}
\ and \
(\lambda x_0. \underline{false})^4 \underline{true} = \underline{false}
$$

So
$$
(\lambda x_0. \underline{false})^5 \underline{true}
= (\lambda x_0. \underline{false})((\lambda x_0. \underline{false})^4 \underline{true})
= (\lambda x_0. \underline{false})\underline{false}
= \underline{false}
$$

$\square$

Are the steps correct and reasonable? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco thank you